# Get AD info for user in Windows Authentication for ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Working on an intranet app in .NET Core and I'd like to retrieve information connected to the AD users. Currently, all authentication is handled by Windows and works great. Is there a way I can pull data from AD? I'd like to get information like first and last name, e-mail, ID, etc.

Comment: I think for now this is your only option.  https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Comment: If you have the 4.6.1 framework available via project.json you could use this https://vikutech.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/ldap-with-aspnet-core-identity-in-mvc-core.html

Comment: @K7Buoy, This is for .NET Core and it's not compatible with the old .NET frameworks packages. Thanks though!

Comment: You can still import older frameworks but perhaps that is what you are trying to avoid.  

"frameworks": {    "netcoreapp1.1": {      "dependencies": {        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {          "version": "1.1.0"        }      },      "imports": [        "dotnet5.6",        "portable-net45+win8"      ]    },    "net461": {    }

Comment: @K7Buoy - I've tried that before and variations of it, but all I get are errors stating netcoreapp1.1 is not comparable with net461.

Comment: @K7Buoy - Doh! I didn't realize I needed to remove the .NETCore.App from the dependencies section at the top of project.json. Now I can get the 4.6.1 framework to go. Let me try that link you posted and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I hope it all works for you.  I am using custom claims from the db as our AD was just too rubbish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a week of trying this and that, I finally made headway using the Novell.Directory.Ldap package. It was much easier to troubleshoot and I didn't have to worry about running the dual framework.

First, go to the Package Manager Console and type:

```
Install-Package Novell.Directory.Ldap
```

This will load the package to your project and add it in the project.json.

There are a few examples out there, but after looking at most of them, they were not really what I needed. I ended up with the following code:

```
        var logPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        var logWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(logPath);
        var user = "cn="+User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        logWriter.WriteLine("Current Ldap results:");

        LdapConnection ADconn = new LdapConnection();
        ADconn.Connect("DC IP address", 389);
        ADconn.Bind("DOMAIN\\username", "password");
        logWriter.WriteLine(ADconn.GetSchemaDN());

        LdapSearchResults lsc = ADconn.Search("ou=OrgUnit,dc=DOMAIN,dc=com",       
            LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB,
            user, attrs, false);
        while (lsc.hasMore())
        {
            LdapEntry nextEntry = null;
            try
            {
                nextEntry = lsc.next();
            }
            catch (LdapException e)
            {
                logWriter.WriteLine("Error: " + e.LdapErrorMessage);
                //Exception is thrown, go for next entry
                continue;
            }
            DisplayName = nextEntry.getAttribute("displayName").StringValue;
            UserADId = new Guid((byte[])(Array)nextEntry.getAttribute("objectGuid").ByteValue).ToString();
            EMail = nextEntry.getAttribute("mail").StringValue;
            logWriter.WriteLine(DisplayName);
            logWriter.WriteLine(UserADId);
            logWriter.WriteLine(EMail);

        }
        logWriter.Dispose();
        //Procced 

        //While all the entries are parsed, disconnect   
        ADconn.Disconnect();
```

Using Windows Authentication, this allows the user's attributes to be pulled from AD. Once pulled, you can assign them to variables and use them! It also creates a TMP file in your C:\Windows\Temp\ folder that acts as a debugger in deployment.

Hope this helps out others!

Comment: where did you put this code? Inside a Controller? Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @Diego - Yes, I put it in my main controller under an IActionResult that calls a page listed with the AD data.

Answer (score 10):

Using.net core 2.1.1

Install "System.DirectoryServices" from NuGet

```
        using System.DirectoryServices;

        var name = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];  *@I was getting name as domain\\name @*
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(); 
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(name=" + name + "))";
        SearchResult userProperty = ds.FindOne();

        var userEmail = userProperty.Properties["mail"][0];
        var userName = userProperty.Properties["displayname"][0];
```

Comment: This worked for me. Only change needed was in the filter because my company uses the property "samaccountname".

Comment: DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://bla.bli", ldapuser, ldappw);
 DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);