# Can I get a users identity from an email address instead of a username in ASP.NET Core and DirectoryServices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, active-directory

I have a need for users to be able to enter an email address and after clicking submit, I'd like to get some Active Directory information from the email address entered. Our usernames unfortunately don't follow a single naming convention so I'm unable to reliably guess the username from the email address entered.

I'm fine with looking up information from a username, is there a way of back tracking to an identity from an email address entered using DirectoryServices or something similar?

Thanks,

Edit and some clarifiction:

On the form, it's not the authenticated users email address that I would be looking up, it's the email address that was entered in the form.

```
    public class ManagerDetails
    {
        public string GetManagersName(string emailAddress)
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal mgr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, emailAddress);

            string managersName = mgr.GivenName;

            return managersName;
        }
    }
```

This piece of code works, but only if the username matches the email address.

For example, this works, Joe.Bloggs@mydomain.com (email) and Joe.Bloggs (domain username).

If it's Joe.Bloggs@mydomain.com (email) and BloggsJ (domain username) it fails.

This is obviously because it's using the email address as the full username but hopefully it explains what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps you can show how you are looking up users now, then we can help guide you?

Comment: So what happens if an employee leaves and a new one gets assigned the same email? You can look up by email in AD (that's what `Directory` means), but you *can't* use that to authenticate.

Comment: As for getting information from the AD account, again, you get that from the *account* you've already authenticated, not the email. While yes, you can look up an account by email, the *user's* account is the one you've already authenticated and whose profile you can already access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get AD info for user in Windows Authentication for ASP .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517448/get-ad-info-for-user-in-windows-authentication-for-asp-net-core)

Comment: Added some more info, hopefully it clarifies what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still refining but this works, it allows me to use directory searcher to get a name from an email address entered.

```
        public string GetManagersName(string emailAddress)
        {
            string userName = GetManagersUserNameByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

            string managersName = usr.GivenName;

            return managersName;
        }

        private string GetManagersUserNameByEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
        {
            DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            adSearcher.Filter = ("mail=" + emailAddress);
            adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");

            SearchResult result = adSearcher.FindOne();

            DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

            string userName = user.Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();

            return userName;
        }
```

Comment: If you want to include secondary email addresses too (because any account can have more than one email address assigned) then you can use `adSearcher.Filter = ("proxyAddresses=smtp:" + emailAddress);`

Comment: Coincidentally I've just run into that issue. Thanks for that.