# .net core 5 on IIS how to read objectGUID and e-mail?

Tags: authentication, iis, .net-core

I have a .netcore 5 MVC/webAPI application setup with windows auth hosted in IIS:

Startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Startup.cs Configure

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

When I do httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name I get domain\username, but I don't know how to get e-mail and objectGuid, I have tried context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) but I get null.

I appreciate your help,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get AD info for user in Windows Authentication for ASP .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517448/get-ad-info-for-user-in-windows-authentication-for-asp-net-core)

Comment: Normally, if you can get domain\username, you can also get -mail and objectGuid. Where did you get them? In the middleware or in the controller or elsewhere?